# Asynchronous Repeating Scheduled Task

Tags: android, android-asynctask

How does one create an `AsyncTask` which keeps running itself after a fixed interval of time.

For eg. get data from server every 5 minutes and give *notification* to caller thread that it has received the data. I searched on the forum but could not find much. What I have gathered so far is that

1) A UI thread will call `AsyncTask`

2) `onPrExecute` for UI thread access before executing

3) `OnPostExecute` for UI thread access after executing

I dont need to show any progress update to the user. Also, the task will be destroyed when the app closes. Any tutorial for this will he helpful

Comment: I will prefer you to use Service.

Comment: use service with alarm service manager

Comment: @hotveryspicy: In that case wont IntentService would be better ? Becuase I dont need to handle multiple requests . Also is there any tutorial for that

Comment: That depends on you because [IntentService](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/IntentService.html) is subclass of Service itself, `IntentService` are best as they run in separate thread and also get killed(implicit) once its work gets over, Moreover its also handles multiple request via making a request queue.

Comment: @hotveryspicy: Any tutorial for IntentService running itself again and again after some fixed interval

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As other suggested in the comments. So let me elaborate it more.

DON'T USE AsyncTask. INSTEAD GO FOR IntentService ONLY.

1. Make a class extends IntentService
2. Use Alarm Manager to trigger a intent to your own service with specific action item
3. Define a Interface to be used to notify client of this service.
4. Maintain a list of these interface implemenation object provided by its client.
5. in onHandleIntent(Intent intent) identify the call by checking action.
6. Initiate the data fetch request directly on intentService as the use worker thread to work and in the end call update delegate of the interface object list you maintained.
7. Make methods to Let Activity register and unregister from listening these updates.
8. Which is actually adding the interface implementation provided by them in the list you maintained and remove from it when unregister gets called.
9. make sure activity register itself in onResume and unregister itself in the onPause.
10. Either use Repeating alarm or initiate one again in the end of single operation run.
    I hope it helps :)

Comment: Wont IntentService alone be able to do it. Why do we need Async TAsk with it ?

Comment: Ahhh. Yes how can i forgot. Don't use AsyncTask. IntentService is able to do that

Comment: AsyncTask needs to attach itself with a context. 
By following this it will work as independent module in your application. that provides updates to anyone who register to it.

This will going to work great. Trust me.

Comment: `AsyncTask needs to attach itself with a context` perfectoo.

Comment: But don't `IntentService`s run in the main UI thread unlike `AsyncTask`s?

Comment: Is there any tutorial for using intentservice with alarm manager the best  could get is www.vogella.com/articles/AndroidService/article.html

Comment: you just have to add intent to your service to the alarm manager to trigger after a specific time. which is simple using alarm manager. Search for IntentService sample.

Answer (score 0):

You can schedule the `AsyncTask` to repeat at a fixed rate using [Timer.scheduleAtFixedRate](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/Timer.html#scheduleAtFixedRate%28java.util.TimerTask,%20long,%20long%29).

Comment: @hotveryspicy, that is not true. You need to call the `execute()` method to make it run in its own thread, but you can only call this from a looper thread - which is usually the main thread.

Comment: Thats what I'm saying when you run Asyntask and if user do any interaction with UI then User feels flickering(which is bad).

Comment: @Phil: So i guess when I use TimerTask each time asyncTask will spawn its own thread rather than running in the Main or UI thread

Comment: @ankuj, that entirely depends on how you implement it

Comment: I should also note that, as stated above, the async task needs to be started on a looper thread. So you will need to start the async task from the main thread, on an interval - which you can do using the `Context.runOnUIThread` instance method.

Answer (score 0):

Try this..

**-** Better use `Service` to make this work again and again.

**-** Now you can use **bound or unbound** `Service`. If you want the Service to be bounded to the Activity then use Bound Service else use UnBound Service.

**-** If would be even better to use `IntentService`, as here you **don't need the task keep running, but runs after certain amount of time.**

**See this link:**

http://mobile.tutsplus.com/tutorials/android/android-fundamentals-intentservice-basics/

Answer (score 0):

I wrote an app that fires `AsyncTask`s on a regular interval, except that they persist even when the app is closed. Anyway, here's what I had to do:

1. Create a `PendingIntent` (via `getBroadcast()`) that contains an `Intent` that contains an action.
2. Supply the `PendingIntent` to the system's `AlarmManager` and set the intervals.
3. Declare a `BroadcastReceiver` in the manifest to catch the action string supplied to the `Intent` in no. 1.
4. In the `onReceive()` method of your `BroadcastReceiver`, fire the `AsyncTask`.