# Scheduling Repeating Tasks in a Service

Tags: android, android-service, android-alarms

I need to repeat a task every 1 hour in the background (I am sending some info to my server).

1. I tried to use a service with a post delay handler calling it self.

   ```
      handler = new Handler(); 
   runable = new Runnable() { 

       @Override 
       public void run() { 
           try{

           //sending info to server....

           }
           catch (Exception e) {
               // TODO: handle exception
           }
           finally{
               //also call the same runnable 
               handler.postDelayed(this, 1000*60*60); 
           }
       } 
   }; 
   handler.postDelayed(runable, 1000*60*60);
   ```

This did not work, in small time interval of 1 minutes it worked fine, when i changed it to 5 minutes it worked for about 5 repetitions and then the timing got wrong and after an hour the service shut down.

2. i want to try to use a AlarmManager but in the [documentation](https://developer.android.com/training/scheduling/alarms.html)
   it says "As of Android 4.4 (API Level 19), all repeating alarms are inexact" 
   does anybody know how inexact it is? is it seconds? ,minutes? 
   can i rely on this to work on time?
3. does anybody have any other suggestions for repeating tasks in a service?

Thanks

Comment: If you want your alarm to set for precise time then use setExact method, then in broadcastreiver  set your alarm  with same setExact method and call your service.

Comment: The alarmManager doesn't have a setExact function. In the documentation it has but when i press ctrl+space in eclipse i get only set(...), setInexactRepeating(...) and  setRepeating().

Comment: Have you tried copying that method name, and try to find why it is not supporting?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13115809/asynchronous-repeating-scheduled-task?answertab=active#tab-top

Answer (score 3):

You can use this      This Code is for repeated calling on oncreate method or anyother thing

```
public void callAsynchronousTask() {
    final Handler handler = new Handler();
    Timer timer = new Timer();
    TimerTask doAsynchronousTask = new TimerTask() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            handler.post(new Runnable() {
                public void run() {
                    try {
                        onCreate();

                    } catch (Exception e) {

                    }
                }
            });
        }
    };
    timer.schedule(doAsynchronousTask, 0, 1000); //execute in every 1000 ms
}
```